# Using Characters in String to Create New Variables

Tags: r, string

Data I'm scrapping off of the web uses the * character to denote one thing and + to denote another.

Here's an example of what it looks like:

```
# Original Data
original_df <- data.frame(c("Randy Watson*+", "Cleo McDowell*", "Darryl Jenks"))
names(original_df) <- 'nameinfo'

original_df
```

I want to transform the data to look like this output:

```
# What I want the Data to look like
name <- c("Randy Watson", "Cleo McDowell", "Darryl Jenks")
this_thing <- c("1", "1", "0")
that_thing <- c("1", "0", "0")
desired_df <- data.frame(name_column, this_thing, that_thing)

desired_df
```

I basically want to use the prsense of * to denote one flag variable, + for another variable, then remove either * or + from the nameinfo field and use it as a new variable name.

Thanks.

Comment: Check out my [`needleInHaystack` function here](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/10567936). Usage would be `needleInHaystack(c("*", "+"), original_df$nameinfo)`. Some cleanup would be required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grepl` will work well here:

```
original_df$this_thing <- grepl("\\*", original_df$nameinfo)
original_df$that_thing <- grepl("\\+", original_df$nameinfo)
original_df$nameinfo <- gsub("\\*|\\+", "", original_df$nameinfo)
original_df

##        nameinfo this_thing that_thing
## 1  Randy Watson       TRUE       TRUE
## 2 Cleo McDowell       TRUE      FALSE
## 3  Darryl Jenks      FALSE      FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks @Tyler for the help.  Any idea how to have it return 1 instead of true and 0 instead of false?

Comment: Logicals can be cerced to numeric with `as.numeric`; try `as.numeric(c(T, F))`.

Comment: Wouldn't an `sapply` be useful here?

Comment: @AnandaMahto Probably, but for 2 items (columns) I probably wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach, using the character class `:punct:` and a single `gsub` call

```
original_df <- data.frame(c("Randy Watson*+", "Cleo McDowell*", "Darryl Jenks"))
names(original_df) <- 'nameinfo'    
original_df$this_thing <- c("1", "1", "0")
original_df$that_thing <- c("1", "0", "0")
original_df$nameinfo <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", original_df$nameinfo)
```

Comment: Thanks @lawyeR, the last line is helpful.  Unfortunately the main thing for me is the flags of 0/1 or F/T for the two variables.